# (TI_84 Plus) Comparing a variable to a list of numbers for a 'if' statement

Tags: list, texas-instruments, ti-basic

Iam trying to compare a variable to a list of numbers and return true if thoses number match the value of the variable.

```
:1-> X
:If L1=X
:Then
:Disp TRUE
:End
```

But it doesn't work, and I have three numbers in the list which are one, two, and three
Anyone know if iam doing it wrong and if so is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to iterate through the list and compare each value to X until you find a mismatch. Disp False if you find one, and Disp True if you reach the end of the program without finding any mismatches.

Comment: Thanks for the help but what do you mean by "iterate through" do i use a something for that? -iam kinda new to this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly compare a single variable to an entire list, but you can iterate through the list and compare it to each entree.

This code will loop through the list, and run the check for each item. The result will be that `TRUE` will be outputted for each item in the list that equals `1`. (In your case only once.)

```
:1-> X
:For(I,1,dim(L1))
:If L1=X
:Then
:Disp "TRUE"
:End
:End
```

You can also modify the code to display also display `FALSE` for each item which doesn't match.

```
:1-> X
:For(I,1,dim(L1))
:If L1=X
:Then
:Disp "TRUE"
:Else
:Disp "FALSE"
:End
:End
```

Or you could have it only display `TRUE` or `FALSE` once, to represent if any matching items exist.

```
:1-> X
:For(I,1,dim(L1))
:If L1=X
:Then
:Disp "TRUE"
:Return
:End
:End
:Disp "FALSE"
```